# How to select some rows if one condition is true and others if another condition is true?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to select some rows from a table if a certain condition is true, then if another condition is true to select some others and else (in end) to select some other rows. The main problem is that I want to insert a parameter from command line like this:

```
if exists(select a.* from a
left join b on a.id=b.id
where b.id=:MY_PARAMETER)
else if exists
(select c.* from c where c.id=:Another_Parameter)
else
(select * from b)
```

I understand that I am doing something wrong but I can not figure out what. I tried using CASE-Then but I couldn't find a way to adapt to the solution. Any idea? Thanks

PS: I read some other posts about something like this but as I explained I am having difficulties through this.

<===Edited=====>

Hoping I am clarifying something:

```
select
case when b.id=6
then (select * from a)
else (select a.* from a join b
on b.aid=a.aid)
end
from a join b
on b.aid=a.aid
join c
on b.id=c.bid
where b.id=:num
```

In this case the problem is that it does not allow to return more than one value in the CASE statement.

Comment: Do you mean a union query? e.g Select Id,Description From A Where somecondition union Select Id,Description From B Where Someothercondition

Comment: No, I want to retrieve some rows if some condition is true, for example if the MY_PARAMETER=10 and if MY_PARAMETER=20 to select some other rows and if MY_PARAMETER has another value to select some new rows. I do not want to merge the results.

Comment: you can go for plsql and create your own query with passed parameter and open it with a refcursor.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am new to pl/sql so I would like to solve this through sql, but if you can help me to do this through pl/sql I would be very thankful :)

Comment: So No you did mean a uinion query then? ...

Comment: Well I did not know how to solve the problem, that is why I did not confirmed your question. Anyway thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union should do just fine, for example for your first example (this will work only if tables a, b and c have similar column order and types):

```
select a.* from a
left join b on a.id=b.id
where b.id=:MY_PARAMETER
UNION
select c.* from c where c.id=:Another_Parameter
and not exists(select a.* from a
left join b on a.id=b.id
where b.id=:MY_PARAMETER)
UNION
select b.* from b
where not exists
(select c.* from c where c.id=:Another_Parameter
and not exists(select a.* from a
left join b on a.id=b.id
where b.id=:MY_PARAMETER))
and not exists (select a.* from a
left join b on a.id=b.id
where b.id=:MY_PARAMETER)
```

In order to build more effective query, I need more specific example.

---

```
SELECT a.* FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.id = :MY_PARAMETER
UNION
SELECT a.* FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN c ON b.id = c.bid
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM b WHERE
                 b.id = :MY_PARAMETER)
AND c.id = :Another_Parameter
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, in my case the three tables have not the same number or type of parameters. Table A is connected with table B through FK and also table B with table C with FK with each other. I will enter through command line a value of table B. If this value is found in the JOIN of A&B I want to retrieve some rows from A and if that value is not found in A&B JOIN but is related to a particular value of C then I want to retrieve some other rows from A (again, just different rows)

Comment: @AlbanoVito That simplifies it, edited an answer - check the second query.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now, I tried in Oracle but it is returning: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

Comment: I found an information that explains that "You can't put a CLOB in the WHERE clause.". Is this comming because of the 'where not exists (Select * from..)'?

Comment: @AlbanoVito What is the types of columns a.id and c.id?

Comment: I made the query to select only one value from Table A for testing it but it is not returning anything when "MY_PARAMETER" is not found in the B table.

Comment: The ID column types are Numbers but as I replied above I found that the query is not working if the value entered is no found in the B table.

Comment: @AlbanoVito Provide some sample data, on which query isn't working right, it's hard to tell what is wrong without it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35738/discussion-between-albano-vito-and-mikhail)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks from Mikhail, the right query that solved my problem is this:

```
select a.*
from a
join b
on a.id1=b.id2
where b.id1= :value and exists 
(select b.id1 from bwhere b.id1 = :value)
union all
select *
from a
where exists (select * from c where c.id1=5 and c.id2=:value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DECODE?

```
Select DECODE(EXISTS(*Case1*),*First case column*,
    DECODE(EXISTS(*Case2*),*Second case column*,*Default case column*)) FROM ...
```